# SQL: join two tables (LEFT OUTER JOIN) then update values

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql

Im trying to update a value in one column based on a value in another table.

I can do this if the columns are all in the same table like this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_date = REPLACE (post_date, 'X', 'Y') 
WHERE meta_value = 'Z';
```

But I need to join two tables first before I can update:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta ON post_id = post_id
```

How can I update based on the two tables I have joined?

Comment: What database you use, actually? :)

Comment: Im using Mysql, its working now thanks hgulyan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way, if you use **SQL Server**

```
UPDATE WP
SET WP.post_date = REPLACE(WPM.post_date, 'X', 'Y') 
FROM wp_posts WP 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_id
WHERE WP.meta_value = 'Z';
```

**UPDATE:**

If you're using **MySQL**. Here's Update for *MySQL*

```
UPDATE wp_posts WP 
   LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_id
SET WP.post_date = REPLACE(WPM.post_date, 'X', 'Y') 
WHERE meta_value = 'Z';
```

Comment: Im getting a syntax error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'FROM wp_posts WP LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_i' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server**

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
post_date = REPLACE (post_date, 'X', 'Y')
FROM wp_posts WP LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_id
WHERE meta_value = 'Z';
```

**MySQL**

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_id 
SET post_date = REPLACE (post_date, 'X', 'Y')
WHERE meta_value = 'Z'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 UPDATE wp_posts SET post_date = REPLACE (WPM.post_date, 'X', 'Y')
 FROM wp_posts AS WP
 LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta AS WPM ON WP.post_id = WPM.post_id
 WHERE WP.meta_value = 'Z'
```

Comment: @hgulyan Thank you, now I corrected that...I was typing quickly, didn't see the fields with the same name